# Encoding multi-letter identifiers in LaTeX for proper speech output with MathJax's Speech Rule Engine

Tags: accessibility, mathrm

I need to encode multi-letter identifiers (words or units) in a mathematical expression. I also need the expression to be coded such that MathJax's Speech Rule Engine (SRE) will generate the correct speech text for the equation so that screen-reading software will speak the expression correctly (the content is in a Canvas LMS page in a higher ed course and needs to be accessible).

As you know,in LaTeX, text enclosed in dollar signs $...$ or within [...] is interpreted as math and, by default, it is typeset in italics, following the common style for variables in mathematical formulas. LaTeX treats individual characters as separate mathematical entities (or variables). For example, $abc$ would be interpreted as the variables a, b, and c multiplied together.

I was told that when you want to use multi-letter identifiers, words, or units in a mathematical formula, they should be typeset in an upright font to avoid confusion and to use the \mathrm{...} command to do this. For example, \mathrm{abc} treats "abc" as a single entity and renders it in an upright font.

So, if I want velocity equals distance over time I'd write:

```
\[\mathrm{velocity} = \frac{\mathrm{distance}}{\mathrm{time}}\]
```

However, the speech text generated by MathJax 3.2.2 using its default MathSpeak Verbose setting is the following:

```
v e l o c i t y equals StartFraction d i s t a n c e Over t i m e EndFraction
```

Note how the word "identifiers" are still spaced out as single letters. MathJax's Speech Rule Engine is not interpreting the \mathrm content as a single identifier.

The expected output would be:

```
velocity equals StartFraction distance Over time EndFraction
```

Is there a more correct way to encode words as a single identifier? Or, is MathJax not interpreting it correctly and it's a bug in MathJax's SRE?

Comment: btw... I also tried
```\[\mathit{velocity} = \frac{\mathit{distance}}{\mathit{time}}\]```
and the only difference was that MathJax added the word "italic" in front of the letters:
```italic v e l o c i t y equals StartFraction italic d i s t a n c e Over italic t i m e EndFraction```

Comment: mathjax isn't clearly on topic here but does it do better with `\textrm{velocity}` ?

Comment: That works -- looks the same and generates the correct speech text output:

```velocity equals distance times time```

I wonder if there are any issues with how it would be interpreted in expression explorers, etc. with marking it up as text mode content and not an identifier?

Comment: If you are using `unicode-math` package, what do `\mathrm`, `\mathtextrm` and `\mathnormal` do?

Comment: Unfortunately, in my use case the content is in a 3rd party tool (the Canvas Learning Management System (LMS)). They are using an ancient version of MathJax (2.7.7) and it does not support the unicode-math package.